# Understanding Schwartz functions

Tags: functional-analysis, schwartz-space

[The Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) $\mathcal{S}$ is the space of smooth,
infinitely differentiable and rapidly decreasing functions on
 $\mathbb{R^n.}$ Using a set builder we can rewrite $\mathcal{S}$ as:
 $$ \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^n})=\{f\in
 C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n}):||f||_{\alpha,\beta}<\infty \,, \forall
 \alpha, \beta\} \tag{1} $$ Where $\alpha,\beta$ are [multi-indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation)
 and $$ ||f||_{\alpha,\beta}=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R^n}} \left|x^\alpha
 D^\beta f(x)\right| \tag{2} $$

---

**Questions:**

1. How can one interpret intuitively the definition of the norm of $f$ given in $(2)?$ And how does it imply that such $f$'s (and all its derivatives) should be decaying?
2. By "rapidly decreasing functions", is it hinted that the decay rate of such functions is *exponential?* (otherwise, "rapid" with respect to what?)
3. Finally, how can one explain that any smooth function $f$ with compact support is in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^n})?$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. From (2) it follows that
   $$
   |D^\beta f(x)|\le\frac{\|f\|_{\alpha,\beta}}{|x|^\alpha}.
   $$
   $f$ and all its derivatives decay at $\infty$ faster than any negative power.
2. The decay may not be exponential. Consider for instance $e^{-(1+x^2)^a}$ with $0<a<1/2$.
3. If the support of $f$ is $K$, then for all multi-indices $\alpha,\beta$
   $$
   \sup_{x\in K}\bigl|x^\alpha D^\beta f(x)\bigr|<\infty.
   $$

Comment: What does $|x|^{\alpha}$ mean?

Comment: $|x|$ is the euclidian norm of $x$.